# Portugal Customs - goods in quantities greater than those permitted

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, local-customs, portugal

I am a Brazilian with a Portuguese resident authorization.

I will visit my hometown in Rio Grande do Sul state and I would like to bring a kind of tea (Chimarrão tea) to here. As I will have a bunch of slots in my baggage, I would like to bring 12KG of tea. I consume almost 2KG by month, so, I will have tea for 6 months. The tea is not illegal and it can be bought in Portugal, but it so expensive.

I am checking this [page](https://www.ana.pt/en/lis/passenger-guide/plan-your-trip/customs) and it says that I cannot bring goods in quantities greater than those permitted. However, I did not find what is the permitted quantities (I found only for alcohol). I know that in Brazil, usually the quantity as 12.

What is the permitted quantity in Portugal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from a handful special products like alcohol and tobacco, if something is allowed at all, the main limit is the value (€430 when traveling by air, as the site explains).

That limit only applies to personal effects, which means that importing a large quantity of anything could raise suspicion that you are really importing the goods with an intent to resell them. There is no set limits for this, it's left at the discretion of border guards as far as I know.

If you exceed the allowance, get things delivered by post or import things commercially, it is still allowed but you would be liable for VAT and customs duty (where applicable).

Comment: Adding the following would make the answer more complete: **Anything in excess of the amount [€ 430] will be liable for VAT and customs duty.**

Comment: And you need to declare it by going through the red channel, not wait until they ask or check.

Comment: Thanks, I expanded the answer a bit to explain that.